# saving big matrices in python : zeros saved instead of data

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

i am working in a laboratory and i got a problem on ipython 2.7 ; when I try to save (numpy.save) big matrices of 80*10*284*300 the matrix saved is only partly filled. Thus when I load the saved matrix (numpy.load) only a small portion of the first data are stored and the rest of the matrix is filled with zeros. Do I lack memory on my disk ? The .npy files created are pretty big (4gB with the mostly empty matrix, maybe the fully filled matrix would be too big for my disk?)

Thanks you in advance for any help on this problem

Comment: What's the max filesize your filesystem allows?

Comment: Why are the numpy files that big? Assuming you save 8 byte per entry this makes 80*10*284*300*8 byte = 545 MB. Where do the other 3.5 GB come from?

Comment: Are you using structured arrays with many fields? If so, your problems may be solved in numpy 1.9, see [this commit](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/commit/fc50d27b4e125052d44b0643bc344e4c5062316a).

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The numpy file is big because it's actually 32 bits per entry as we use float32 as the format of our data (we are dealing with pictures actually). I don't know what is the maw filesize of the filesystem, how could I check that?

Comment: also I don't use structured arrays as far as I know, the matrix are allocated via numpy.zeros without further treatment.

Comment: 32 bit is 4 bytes, so the array size is actually the half of what @a_guest indicates, i.e. around 260MB. Try saving `np.random.randn(80, 10, 284, 300)` on disk, then reloading it into a new variable and comparing the two. I would hope they would be equal.

Comment: Are you by chance using OSX? If yes, this OSX C library bug may be relevant: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/574  Also, what Numpy version do you have?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake the size is actually 100*80*384*285 so I expect 6.84Gb which I have actually. The problem of the zeros seems not to arise for a computer with sufficient place on the disk so I think zeros are written when no place can be given anymore to "actual" floats. Thanks for the help